# Why Flat File is not Loading in SSIS Source?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, package

I have a below text file as source which is trying to load into database . But in the very first stage throwing error like

> Source [8]: The data type for "Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[ SubName]" is DT_NTEXT, which is not supported with ANSI files. Use DT_TEXT instead and convert the data to DT_NTEXT using the data conversion component.

```
CAS, SubName, ListCode, Type, CountryCode, ListName
^1000413-72-8^,^fasiglifam^,^447^,^Chemical Inventory^,^EU^,^ECICS Custom Tariff Codes^
^1000413-72-8^,^fasiglifam^,^0^,^^,^NN^,^SPHERA Global Substance List^
```

[image]

I have used used correct code page in both end and used derived component for the conversion .
Please help me to load source to target as database

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the DT_TEXT in the target to confirm you can load the data without utilizing the derived transformation? If that works you can handle the conversion with a post SQL update statement.

Comment: target is my database . how i can change DT_text .. its just shows me to create table in databse

Comment: On your OLE DB Destination Editor click "New" and edit your target name as desired and attempt to land the data in the db object. No need to alter or change data types.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens generally when you try to use existing "source assistance" element. I was having this problem and I found solution in adding new element(source assistance).
**go SSIS -> SSIS Toolbox**
add new Source Assistant and make configurations for data source you are using, it should work.